# Numeric mathematics, solve an equation with two unknowns.

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the relation $k=450nl+55n+205l+25$ where $k,n,l$ are all integers with $n,l<k$, if we know the upper limit for $k$,e.g. assume $k<=1000$ how many $n$ and $l$ could we find that satisfy the above relation? can the answer be given over a formula?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 & k = 450 nl + 55n + 205 l + 25 \\
\implies & k - 55n -25 = (450n + 205)l \\
\implies & l = \dfrac{k - 55n -25}{450n + 205} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Now you have $n, l < k$ and $k \leq 1000$, so for a given $k$ (say 500), all those **integer** values of $n$ which are less than 500 and gives an **integer** value of $l$ by satisfying (1) will be your solution. So depending on the value of $k$ you may have one / more solutions or no solutions at all (because of the integer constraint).